# Java: Does Throwing An Exception Kill Its Method?

Tags: java, exception

For instance:

```
public String showMsg(String msg) throws Exception {
    if(msg == null) {
        throw new Exception("Message is null");
    }
    //Create message anyways and return it
    return "DEFAULT MESSAGE";
}

String msg = null;
try {
    msg = showMsg(null);
} catch (Exception e) {
    //I just want to ignore this right now.
}
System.out.println(msg); //Will this equal DEFAULT MESSAGE or null?
```

I'm needing to essentially ignore exceptions in certain cases (usually when multiple exceptions can be thrown from a method and one doesn't matter in a particular case) so despite the pathetic example that I used for simplicity will the return in showMsg still run or does the throw actually return the method?

Comment: Your code already shows you what throw does.

Comment: Avoid throwing `new` exceptions, it loses the call stack.

Comment: @jahroy i don`t think so, finally blocks run even after exception

Comment: Running that code should demonstrate that msg is null because the Exception was thrown.

Comment: @MartinV. - Yep... thought about my silly blanket statement for a split second and deleted it.

Comment: Please don't focus too much on the sample code. I tried to write something very simple for the sake of the question, in reality the situation would be a lot more complicated than passing a null value and wanting to ignore an exception caught on that value.

Comment: Yes... but (as Hovercraft has pointed out) you could have simply answered your question by running your sample code.  Regardless of how complicated your real code is, your sample code will demonstrate the concept perfectly.

Comment: True, any many times I do try myself, but in order for the sake of documentation I also try and ask them as a question on the site.

Comment: I think this concept is covered **VERY** well in any place that discusses the fundamentals of Java.  I don't think you need to ask the question here just to provide a potential reference for others ;-)

Comment: Fair enough, feel free to vote for a close. Sorry to ask such an ignorant question.

Comment: No worries at all... Don't see a need to close.  I would if I could find a duplicate, but I haven't seen any.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

The `return` statement will *not* run if the exception is thrown. Throwing an exception causes the control flow of your program to go immediately to the exception's handler(*), skipping anything else in the way. So in particular `msg` will be `null` in your print statement if an exception was thrown by `showMsg`.

(*) Except that statements in `finally` blocks will run, but that's not really relevant here.

Comment: Another _exception_ to the rule (no pun intended) would be if the method in question _catches_ the exception.  You _can_ explicitly throw an exception in a try block and catch it yourself in the corresponding catch block.  That being said, your answer probably covers this scenario with your choice of words: "_...causes control flow to go immediately to the exception's_ **handler**".

Comment: If you return something from inside a finally block, it still gets returned despite the exception being thrown.